# Are the ministers in Eph. 4:11 a list of "Formalized" leadership elders in the early Church?

Tags: early-church, ministers, eldership, local-church

**Considerations** The early local churches consisted of **saints, elders, deacons** according to Philippians 1:1. And some biblical researchers consider there to just be a general unformalized ministry during the New Testament times (in line with this verse). Others consider the list of ministers in Ephesians 4:ll to be evidence of a more formal leadership ministry in the local church.

We know that most of the Christians were familiar with the make-up of the Synagogue in Israel at that time, which had a leadership that consisted of **archisynagogos, hazzans, and almoners**. So they would consider some type of spiritual leadership necessary in the fledgling church, as well.

So is there evidence by the use of these titles in the rest of the verses in the New Testament that backs up the position that there was a formal, ordained leadership in existence at the time of Paul? And that these men in Ephesians 4:11 are indeed those leaders?

For further consideration: do Evangelical Protestants consider this list to be a pattern for modernity? A plurality of elders with these roles in the local church?

Comment: I don't see "elders" in Phil. 1.1. The word "episkopois" does appear, although it probably does not mean "bishops" in the sense it later implied.

Comment: also I think you mean "hazzan" rather than "hazzar" and I wonder it this office was formally established "at the time" - as there was no 'Synagogue in Israel' but (just as with the churches) many synagogues, whose governing traditions were not necessarily uniform.

Comment: @ Dan Fefferman - Thank you for the spelling correction.--- According to Dottard, "elder" and "overseer" are used interchangeably in the N.T. (Acts 20:17,28, 1 Timothy 3:2, etc.)--- Info on the synagogues came from JEWISH BACKGROUNDS ON THE N.T. by Julius Scott, Jr. (Great book.) Thanks for your interaction!

Answer (score 1):

Paul actually has numerous lists of spiritual gift - all of them different and none of them complete.  All were clearly intended to be examples of the many and diverse ways that the Holy Spirit could empower people for ministry.

**Eph 4:11**

- apostles
- prophets
- evangelists
- shepherds/pastors
- teachers

**Rom 12:6, 7**

- prophets
- serving
- teaching
- encouraging
- generosity
- leadership
- mercy

**1 Cor 12:7-10**

- wisdom
- knowledge
- faith/belief
- healing
- miracles
- prophecy
- distinguishing of spirits
- tongues
- interpretation of tongues

**1 Cor 12:28**

- apostles
- prophets
- teachers
- miracle workers
- healing
- helpfulness
- administration
- tongues

Now, whatever one says about these lists must be said about all the other lists.  None are exhaustive - just illustrations of the numerous ways the Holy Spirit empowers people for service and ministry.

Some of these were appointed by God such as apostles, prophets and healers; while others were elected by the church, eg, elders (Titus 1:5, Acts 14:23, 2 Cor 8:19).  Further, the office of elder appears to have been appointed by election of the congregation (Acts 14:23, 2 Cor 8:19) as is clear from the use of the verb “cheirotoneo” – “to elect by raising the hand” – a practice (and verb) taken from the Greek Senate when voting.

While there is no record of election of deacons, the NT implies this was probably the case.

[Note:  The New Testament uses the terms “elder” and “overseer” interchangeably.  Acts 20:17, 28, 1 Tim 3:2, cf. Tit 1:5, 7, 1 Peter 5:1-3]

Answer (score 1):

"Is there evidence by the use of these titles [Eph 4:11] in the rest of the verses in the New Testament that backs up the position that there was a formal, ordained leadership in existence at the time of Paul?"

No - certainly not in Paul's churches although perhaps to some extent in Jerusalem. What the NT describes in Paul's time is various charismatic offices (see list provided in @Dottard's answer) in addition to the beginnings of a more formal set of governing leadership positions that evolved over time. For example, Acts 6:5 describes the creation of the deacon's office but does not use the term. James (the Lord's brother) served as a kind of proto-bishop, but there is no indication that this was a formal office. Also we cannot be sure how quickly such traditions were adopted outside of Jerusalem. James's authority was based at least partly on his family's status, and the deaconate was created in response to a particular, localized issue (material discrimination against Hellenized Jews in that particular congregation).  Also, we should probably think of the churches in Judea, Samaria and the Galilee as more closely following the tradition of the synagogue and Samaritan traditions, while those in the rest of the Roman Empire were less tied to Jewish customs.

In the Pastoral epistles we see the beginning of the offices of bishop and presbyter. For example 1 Timothy 3:1 provides qualification for the bishop's office, and 1 Timothy 4:14 indicates a formalized ordination process, while still retaining the charismatic leadership of prophesy:

> Do not neglect the gift you have, which was conferred on you through the prophetic
> word with the imposition of hands of the presbyterate.

Scholars are divided as to whether this tradition is authentically Pauline.

In the generation after the original apostles, the formalization of church offices still developed gradually, and it took different forms in different places. A fascinating glimpse into this sometimes confusing process is provided in the [Didache](https://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/didache-lake.html) (late 1st or early 2nd century):

> [ch 11] 4 Let every apostle who comes to you be
> received as the Lord, 5 but let him not stay more than one day, or if
> need be a second as well; but if he stay three days, he is a false
> prophet... [ch 13] 1 But every true prophet who wishes to
> settle among you is worthy of his food.  2 Likewise a true teacher
> is himself worthy, like the workman, of his food. 3 Therefore thou
> shalt take the firstfruit of the produce of the winepress and of the
> threshing-floor and of oxen and sheep, and shalt give them as the
> firstfruits to the prophets, for they are your high priests... [ch 15] 1
> Appoint therefore for yourselves bishops and deacons worthy of the
> Lord, meek men, and not lovers of money, and truthful and approved,
> for they also minister to you the ministry of the prophets and
> teachers.

In the most general sense, the key charismatic offices (apostles, prophets, teachers) evolved into the formal positions of bishop, presbyter and deacon. But in Paul's churches, none of these offices seems to have been formalized, although this depends somewhat on one's view on the dating of the Pastoral epistles. For the Jerusalem church, however, there is evidence of the deacon's office being a formal one, and James (the Lord's brother) was apparently the central leader of the church, although his putative formal office is not stipulated.